# Access violation with printing double link list

Tags: c, linked-list, access-violation

I need some help in figuring out why I am getting this access violation. This is home work, I have it all written but end up getting an access violation when printing the list. I am trying to print the list forward and reverse. I suspect the problem is in the reverse function. Here is the code and thanks for the help.

*List.h*

```
typedef int Titem;

// Interface of list
typedef struct node *Tpointer;
typedef struct node 
{
    Titem item;
    Tpointer next, previous;
} Tnode;

typedef struct
{
Tpointer first;
Tpointer last;
}Tdbl;


void initialize_dbl (Tdbl *list);
void insert_to_dbl_front (Tdbl *list, Titem data);
void insert_to_dbl_back (Tdbl *list, Titem data);
void print_dbl (Tdbl const list);
void print_dbl_reverse (Tdbl const list);
```

*List.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "List.h"

#define TYPE_INT 0
#define TYPE_FLOAT 1



// Implementation of list (only obj is need in appl)
void initialize_dbl (Tdbl *list) 
{
   list->first = NULL;
   list->last = NULL;
}


void insert_to_dbl_front (Tdbl *list, Titem data)
{
    Tpointer newnode;

    if(list->first == NULL)
    {
       newnode = (Tpointer) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
       newnode->item = data;
       newnode->next = NULL;
       newnode->previous = NULL;
       list->first = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        newnode = (Tpointer) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
        newnode->item = data;
        newnode->next = list->first;
        newnode->previous = NULL;
        list->first = newnode;

    }
}

void insert_to_dbl_back (Tdbl *list, Titem data)
{
    Tpointer newnode;

    newnode = (Tpointer) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    newnode -> item = data;
    if (list->first == NULL)
        list->first = newnode;       //first node
    else
        list->last->next = newnode;  //not first node
    list->last = newnode;
    list->last->next = NULL;
}

void print_dbl (Tdbl const list) 
{
    Tpointer what;

    printf("\nList forward:");
    what = list.first;
    while (what != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", what->item);
        what = what->next;
    }

}


void print_dbl_reverse (Tdbl const list)
{
    Tpointer last = list.last;
    Tpointer temp = NULL;

    printf("\nList reversed: ");
    if(last == NULL)
    {
        printf("");
    }
    else
    {   
        while(last != NULL)
        {
            temp = last->next;  
            last->next = last->previous;
            last->previous = temp;
            last = temp;

        }

        printf("\nList reverse:");

        while (last != NULL) 
        {
            printf("%d ", last->item);
            last = last->next;
        }
    }
}
```

*main.c*

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
Tdbl dbl;
initialize_dbl(&dbl);
print_dbl(dbl);
print_dbl_reverse(dbl);
insert_to_dbl_back(&dbl, 10);
print_dbl(dbl);
print_dbl_reverse(dbl);
insert_to_dbl_front(&dbl, 20);
print_dbl(dbl);
print_dbl_reverse(dbl);
insert_to_dbl_back(&dbl, 30);
print_dbl(dbl);
print_dbl_reverse(dbl);
insert_to_dbl_front(&dbl, 40);
print_dbl(dbl);
print_dbl_reverse(dbl);
insert_to_dbl_back(&dbl, 50);
print_dbl(dbl);
print_dbl_reverse(dbl);


fflush(stdin); getchar();
}
```

I have looked at about 10 different examples of linked lists as well as searched the forum 
for an answer to my question. Every example I have tried with reversing the list seems to do nothing or ends up with this access violation error. Oh yes nothing in the main or header file can be changed.

Comment: Welcome to the SO! Do you want SO community to debug your code?

Comment: Side note: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined as far as C is concerned.

Comment: It would help to see "this access violation error"

Answer (score 1):

In

```
void insert_to_dbl_front (Tdbl *list, Titem data)
{
    Tpointer newnode;

    if(list->first == NULL)
    {
       newnode = (Tpointer) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
       newnode->item = data;
       newnode->next = NULL;
       newnode->previous = NULL;
       list->first = newnode;
    }
```

you don't set `list->last`, so that still is set to `NULL`. However, if `list->first` isn't `NULL`,

```
else
{
    newnode = (Tpointer) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    newnode->item = data;
    newnode->next = list->first;
    newnode->previous = NULL;
    list->first = newnode;

}
```

you never set the `previous` pointer of the currently first node to the new node, so you don't really have a doubly linked list.

And when you insert at the back,

```
void insert_to_dbl_back (Tdbl *list, Titem data)
{
    Tpointer newnode;

    newnode = (Tpointer) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    newnode -> item = data;
    if (list->first == NULL)
        list->first = newnode;       //first node
    else
        list->last->next = newnode;  //not first node
    list->last = newnode;
    list->last->next = NULL;
}
```

You never set the `previous` pointer of the new node. So you still have only a singly linked list. That alone wouldn't cause the access violation, but here **you never set `newnode->previous` to anything**, so it contains whatever bits happened to be at that memory location.

Then in `print_dbl_reverse` you swap some `previous` and `next` pointers and have

```
while (last != NULL) 
{
    printf("%d ", last->item);
    last = last->next;
}
```

at some point that sets `last` to an uninitialised non-`NULL` pointer, which causes the access violation.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of bug in your code. I wrote a simple one so you can study it, but leave writing reverse function to you. Have fun!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "List.h"

#define TYPE_INT 0
#define TYPE_FLOAT 1



// Implementation of list (only obj is need in appl)
void initialize_dbl (Tdbl *list) 
{
   list->first = NULL;
   list->last = NULL;
}


void insert_to_dbl_front (Tdbl *list, Titem data)
{
    Tpointer newnode = (Tpointer) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));;
    newnode->item = data;
    newnode->previous = NULL;
    newnode->next = list->first;

    if(list->first != NULL) 
        list->first->previous = newnode;
    else 
        list->last = newnode;

    list->first = newnode;
}

void insert_to_dbl_back (Tdbl *list, Titem data)
{
    Tpointer newnode = (Tpointer) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    newnode->item = data;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->previous = list->last;

    if (list->first == NULL)
        list->first = newnode;
    else
        list->last->next = newnode;

    list->last = newnode;
}

void print_dbl (Tdbl const list) 
{
    Tpointer what;

    printf("\nList forward: ");
    what = list.first;
    while (what != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", what->item);
        what = what->next;
    }
}


void print_dbl_reverse (Tdbl const list)
{
    Tpointer last = list.last;
    Tpointer temp = last;

    printf("\nList reverse: ");
    while (last != NULL) 
    {
            last = last->previous;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions for debugging this problem.

1) Modify your source code to print debugging statements. You could even have the debug information compiled out based on a #ifdef DEBUG_STATEMENTS flag.

2) You could use a debugger and step through this and/or set breakpoints just before your program crashes. The debugger will work easily, if the program is not a daemon/system service or driver.

Other suggestions I have really revolve around implementation more than debugging and have to do with pre-allocating memory and manipulating your linked list within the pre-allocated memory. However, because that is more complicated than the first two suggestions, I'll stop at the overview of that idea.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I have use the debugging in vs 10 to step through it. But could not figure out what was going on. I will try the suggestions and let you know what I come up with.